# WCF - One single method giving error

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a WCF service and Silverlight app that's been running for a few months now and it's been running fine until today. For some odd reason, there is one method in the service that is giving me an error every time I call it. I've gone so far as commenting out everything the method does, but as soon as I call it from the silverlight app I get that stupid error:NotFound message.

Here's the kicker though... if I run the silverlight app and WCF service on my local machine it runs just fine. It's only when the service is running live on our hosting company's server that I get the error.

Does anyone have ideas??

Comment: Try using Fiddler to examine what is going on over the network in production vs your local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the problem. The class that I'm passing through as a parameter looked something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    private string Name = "";
    public string _Name
    {
        get
        {
            return RegionNameName;
        }
        set
        {
            RegionNameName = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("_Name");
        }
    }


}
```

The [DataMember] attribute placed on top of the private property seems to have caused the problem. Strange thing is that it did work for the last few months.

Anyway, the guy who wrote it has left the company. So I'll be working through the whole thing now. Not quite what I had in mind for work today.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the error NotFound in a Silverlight Client calling a WCF Service normally means that the service method threw an exception. Without further details we won't be able to help.

Comment: I've commented out all the code in that method. So the method is doing nothing and I would still get the error. I also do have error handling in place, but from what I can gather, the code in the method doesn't even run.